# Hide/Show form on button click in Flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, backend

I was learning to create a wtf Flask web form which was:

```
class Update(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    pic = FileField('Update Profile Pic', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg','png'])])
    submit = SubmitField('Update')
```

What I wanted to do was that the form would load on the same page on a button click without making a seperate html page for the form. How can it be done either by using Flask or HTML? If any changes to route have to be made, please mention that as well.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="content-section">
            <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Account Info</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}

                        {% if form.username.errors %}
                        {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        {% else %}
                        {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                        {% if form.email.errors %}
                        {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                            <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        {% else %}
                        {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.pic.label() }}
                        {{ form.pic(class="form-control-file") }}
                        {% if form.pic.errors %}
                        {% for error in form.picture.errors %}
                        <span class="text-danger">{{error}}</span><br>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load your form normally, and set it's visibility to `hidden`. If someone clicks on the button, just change visibility of a form to `visible`.

Example below:

```js
function toggle_display(){
  el = document.querySelector('.content_section');
  
  if(el.style.visibility == 'hidden'){
      el.style.visibility = 'visible'
  }else{
     el.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle_display()">Toggle display</button>

<div class="content_section">See me no more</div>
```

EDIT:

One more thing to mention, `visibility` property when set to `hidden` takes up space, even if it's hidden. To completly remove space that form will take and hide form, set `display` property to `none`. To show it again, set `display` to `block`.

Comment: Thanks, your method worked! But by default the form is visible, how to I set its default visibility to hidden?

Comment: I tried by using a part of above code to set value to 'hidden' but it did not work

Comment: You can simply put it as inline property `<div class="content_section" style="visibility: hidden;">See me no more</div>` . But notice, however, it will take up space (it will just hide form, but the form will act like it's still there ). To hide it completely and remove space that form takes, use `style="display: none;"`. If you decide to use `display` property, to show form again, set display to `block`.